# UIKeyboard crashes when input Chinese in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, crash, calayer, uikeyboard

I have a `UITextField` accept user input to search the content on server side.
Everything goes well when just input English. And when I try to input Chinese, the application crashed (but not every time).

I got the following stack trace:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreGraphics                    0x33a72568 argb32_image_mark + 1732
1   CoreGraphics                    0x33a97f6c argb32_shade + 380
2   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x33dd625c ripl_BltShade + 1116
3   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x33dd578c ripc_DrawShading + 4812
4   CoreGraphics                    0x33a9738e CGContextDrawLinearGradient + 170
5   UIKit                           0x35915a4a UIKBDrawLinearGradient + 38
6   UIKit                           0x35c63abe -[UIKeyboardCandidateUnsplitKeyboardToggleButton toggleButtonBackgroundImageWithHighlight:] + 302
7   UIKit                           0x35c63938 -[UIKeyboardCandidateUnsplitKeyboardToggleButton updateBackgroundImages] + 48
8   UIKit                           0x35c63bd4 -[UIKeyboardCandidateUnsplitKeyboardToggleButton setDrawsBackground:] + 44
9   UIKit                           0x35c636e8 -[UIKeyboardCandidateUnsplitKeyboardToggleButton initWithFrame:] + 108
10  UIKit                           0x35bc05ca -[UIKeyboardCandidateGridHeader initWithFrame:] + 434
11  UIKit                           0x35c605e0 -[UIKeyboardCandidateView_iPhone_Bar initWithFrame:] + 324
12  UIKit                           0x35c5ed72 +[UIKeyboardCandidateView sharedInstance] + 242
13  UIKit                           0x35a5022c -[UIKeyboardImpl updateTextCandidateView] + 340
14  UIKit                           0x358fd648 -[UIKeyboardImpl setCandidates:] + 296
15  UIKit                           0x35a4fda2 -[UIKeyboardImpl updateCandidateDisplayAsyncWithCandidates:forInputManager:] + 146
16  TextInput                       0x394aa802 -[TIWordSearchOperationGetCandidates completeSearchOnMainThreadWithResults:] + 94
17  Foundation                      0x3431049c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 456
18  CoreFoundation                  0x339cd8f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
19  CoreFoundation                  0x339cd158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
20  CoreFoundation                  0x339cbf2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3393f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3393f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
23  GraphicsServices                0x3751e336 GSEventRunModal + 70
24  UIKit                           0x3585b2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

The crash log is almost the same every time the application crashed.
I've spent several days on it and cannot find any solution.

Does anyone know anything about this?

--

I found a problem may cause this issue.

I use ARC in my project, and in the -[viewDidLoad] message of the root view controller, I create a child view controller, and in the child view controller's -[viewDidLoad] message, create an NSTimer and add to current run loop to refresh a sub layer in the child view controller.

After I comment the code of creating NSTimer, the crash goes away.

I will work on it and try to find the reason.

Comment: on simulator or device?

Comment: on device and simulator, both will crash sometimes. and the stack trace is the same.

Comment: is it iOS dependent, I mean have you tried on other iOS?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3644184?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I've tried it. and I'm suer not the same problem. I use iOS5 and the application does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

did  you use  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ,and  not release Context by  UIGraphicsEndImageContext. or something similar.